# pyomo constraint express ranged inequality expressions

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm noob w pyomo. I'd like to do this:

```
for w in ww:
    model.constraints.add(
        100 >= sum(8 * model.w[w, d, s] for d in dd for s in ss) >= 50
    )
```

instead I'd tried this way:

```
for w in ww:
    model.constraints.add(
        100 >= sum(8 * model.w[w, d, s] for d in dd for s in ss)
    )

for w in ww:
    model.constraints.add(
        50 <= sum(8 * model.w[w, d, s] for d in dd for s in ss)
    )
```

but It didn't work. It

```
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
    model=unknown;
        message from solver=<undefined>
```

I'm missing something, can u tell me what?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I found

```
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
    model=unknown;
        message from solver=<undefined>
```

because the model is infeasible.